# TensorFlow doesnt build with debug mode

Tags: gcc, tensorflow, gcc-warning

We are trying to build a TensorFlow test case with debug flag:

> bazel build -c dbg
>   //tensorflow/python/kernel_tests:sparse_matmul_op_test

However the build is failing with below error:

> /usr/include/features.h:330:4: error: #warning _FORTIFY_SOURCE
>   requires compiling with optimization (-O) [-Werror=cpp]
>     warning _FORTIFY_SOURCE requires compiling with optimization (-O)
>
> cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
>
> Target //tensorflow/python/kernel_tests:sparse_matmul_op_test failed
>   to build

We have tried below options to resolve this:

1. built by exporting export CFLAGS and  CXXFLAGS to "-Wno-error"
2. bazel build -c dbg --cxxopt="-Wno-all" --cxxopt="-Wno-error" //tensorflow/python/kernel_tests:sparse_matmul_op_test
3. Tried commenting compiler_flag from third_party/gpus/crosstool/CROSSTOOL.tpl

What is the correct way to suppress these warnings for the build to proceed?

We are using gcc v5.4.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had the same issue recently. It got solved by adding `--copt=-O` and `-c opt` to the build command.

Example:

```
bazel build --copt=-O -c dbg -c opt //tensorflow/python/kernel_tests:sparse_matmul_op_test
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution by @BernardoGO does not work when CUDA build is enabled:

```
$ bazel build --copt=-O -c opt --config cuda -c dbg --strip=never //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package -s

/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_pair.h(327): error: calling a __host__ function("std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator< ::tensorflow::NcclManager::NcclStream *> ::_Rb_tree_const_iterator") from a __device__ function("std::pair< ::std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator< ::tensorflow::NcclManager::NcclStream *> , bool> ::pair< ::std::_Rb_tree_iterator< ::tensorflow::NcclManager::NcclStream *>  &, bool &, (bool)1> ") is not allowed

/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_pair.h(327): error: identifier "std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator< ::tensorflow::NcclManager::NcclStream *> ::_Rb_tree_const_iterator" is undefined in device code

/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_algobase.h(1009): error: calling a __host__ function("__builtin_clzl") from a __device__ function("std::__lg") is not allowed

3 errors detected in the compilation of "/tmp/tmpxft_00007abb_00000000-6_nccl_manager.cpp1.ii".
```

Works only if `--copt=-O` is replaced with `--copt=-O1`, but `-O1` is too much for comfortable debugging.